# React Native TabBarIos Change Bar Size

Tags: react-native, tabbar

How can i change Bar style on TabBarIos ? 
First i tried to remove bar with barTintColor="transparent", after that tried add size on it with StyleSheet params, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The size of *TabBarIos* is fixed. So you can't change it.

I recommend you use *View* to create your own *TabBar*.